# I need to modify default value of some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have to create a schema for Oracle and another one for SQL Server. Is it better to use `alter table` to modify default value (date), or should I use a trigger, since Oracle uses `SYSDATE` and SQL Server uses `GETDATE()`

Comment: It is better to create or modify default value, even if the syntax is different, than to use a trigger. What's the downside if you use different syntax for default values? (You probably already know the downside of triggers.)

Comment: And the syntax for triggers is not different?

Comment: Sound good, I just want know which is better, because I have that create "ALTER TABLE" for all columns(DATE) that need default value.

Comment: I have that modify default value of all columns with DATE type, because the SQL schema is generated automatically by my ORM, and default value of a column(DATE) is distinct between SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: If you creating schema, why you need `alter table`? If you modifying schema, do you want to maintain a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I think generally it would be better use a default value, without using trigger (my opinion is to use triggers only if strictly necessary).  Moreover, trigger difference between MSSQL and ORACLE requests more attention than using DEFAULT SYSDATE rather than DEFAULT GETDATE().

On the other hand, default value will be used ONLY if you don't pass any value with insert command: with trigger you can change values as you want.

I'm facing with similar problem (we have two DB version, MSSSQL and ORACLE, for the same application) and in this case we use DEFAULT value for insert date (eg. column DATA_INS) and trigger for update date (column DATA_UPD) of a record.